# Kill services by name from batch file

Tags: batch-file, asp.net-core, batch-processing

I have multiple processes (dotnet.exe) and i don't want to kill them all using something like:

```
taskkill /F /IM dotnet.exe
```

Those processes are, in fact, some microservices (under .net core) and i want to kill them by service name.

Obviously, you cannot do something like: `taskkill /F /IM WanVet.Micro.AppointmentManagement.Read` because that isn't a process.

[image: microservices]

[image: processes]

Is there a way to do this without PID?

Comment: Are these windows services or just long running apps? (if apps you should really think about making them services)

Comment: That's an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq yourservice"

Comment: It works like charm. I wasn't able to find this filter. Thanks a lot Philip. I'll accept this as answer as soon as i'll have the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

net stop

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490715.aspx

Comment: net stop - stops the service but doesn't kill the associated dotnet.exe process.